# Updated: $\frac{d}{dx} [\frac{1}{3}arctan(\frac{3x(1-x^2)}{x^4-4x^2+1})+C]=\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}>0.$

Tags: derivatives

For all C show that $\frac{d}{dx} [\frac{1}{3}arctan(\frac{3x(1-x^2)}{x^4-4x^2+1})+C]=\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}>0.$

So from the first answer below by Chinny84,

$ \frac{1}{3}\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{1}{1+g^2}$ where

$g(x) = \frac{3x\left(1-x^2\right)}{x^4-4x^2+1}$

=$\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{3x(1-x^2)}{x^4-x^2+1}$

Plug that into mathematica and you get $$\frac{x^6+x^4+x^2+1}{(x^4-4x^2+1)^2}$$ which you'll note is not the answer we're looking for. What went wrong?

Comment: why is that $C$ even there? what purpose does it serve?

Comment: @abel I don't think it serves any purpose. It was in the book though so I added it. C would go to 0 though when differentiated so it also doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: if my ti-83 is to be believed, you claim $\frac{d}{dx}\frac 13 \tan^{-1}\frac{3x(1-x^2}{x^4 - 4x^2 + 1} = \frac{x^4+1}{x^6 + 1}$ is not true.

Comment: @abel Mathematica does not get this result either. I will have to ask my professor. Do you agree with the result that I ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mechanical question rather than an interesting one..however you can make life easy for yourself by

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{3}\arctan (g(x)) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{d}{dg}\arctan g(x)= \frac{1}{3}\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{1}{1+g^2}
$$
where 
$$
g(x) = \frac{3x\left(1-x^2\right)}{x^4-4x^2+1}
$$